# Is there a way I can determine the source port number?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I am working on a couple of network troubleshooting scenarios and I wanted to check if there is a way I can find out what source port my PC is using to connect to a website? I am using Windows 10.

I tried using netstat -a, but this shows a lot of active connections and if my understanding is correct, the port numbers shown here are destination ports, correct?

[nestat capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbwVv.png)

Comment: Also if I am connected to google.com from my browser currently, can I know using which source port number I am connected to? Is there a command that I can use to view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port numbers are clearly shown in your netstat output, i.e. `TCP 10.0.0.166:2424 13.107.5.88:https`  means that it connected from the local IP 10.0.0.166 source port 2424 to the remote system 13.107.5.88 on port 443 (https). Note that due to NAT the source IP  on the remote system will be different (i.e. your external IP address) and the source port can be different too, but the value can not be detected on the local system.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Steffen, that really clears up things for me. So if I have someone telling me that they are facing intermittent connection issues to their server and I suspect that it is because of ACLs on their router - would there be any way for me to check the exact port number that is being used  so that I can check if that is the case?

Comment: @SailajaAkella: You would need to have access to the point where the problem exists in order to check the source port there. But note that it is unlikely that a specific source port is the problem: source ports are in most cases random (see [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)) and therefore are usually not part of ACLs.